# How to update Visual Studio code to latest version

Tags: version, angular-console

I am not able to install angular-console with VSC due to version mismatch and I am not getting option anywhere as to how to update VSC

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35) you can update / install the latest version of Visual Studio Code.